# How can I mock a service within a React component to isolate unit tests in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to refactor a unit test to isolate a service that calls an API using axios from the component calling the service.

The service is for the moment really simple:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default class SomeService {
  getObjects() {
    return axios.get('/api/objects/').then(response => response.data);
  }
}
```

Here's a snippet of the component that calls the service:

```js
const someService = new SomeService();

class ObjectList extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    someService.getObjects().then((result) => {
      this.setState({
        data: result,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    // render table rows with object data
  }
}

export default ObjectList
```

I can test that ObjectList renders data as I'd expect by mocking axios:

```js
// ...
jest.mock('axios')

const object_data = {
  data: require('./test_json/object_list_response.json'),
};

describe('ObjectList', () => {
  test('generates table rows from object api data', async () => {

    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(object_data));

    const { getAllByRole } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <table><tbody><ObjectList /></tbody></table>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    await wait();

    // test table contents

  });
});
```

Everything passes without issue. As a mostly academic exercise, I was trying to figure out how to mock SomeService instead of axios, which is where things went awry because I think I don't understand enough about the internals of what's getting passed around.

For example, I figured since SomeService just returns the axios response, I could similarly mock SomeService, sort of like this:

```js
// ...
const someService = new SomeService();

jest.mock('./SomeService')

const object_data = {
  data: require('./test_json/object_list_response.json'),
};

describe('ObjectList', () => {
  test('generates table rows from object api data', async () => {

    someService.getObjects.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(object_data))

// etc.
```

This fails with an error: `Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]`, and the error traces back to this line from `ObjectList`:

```js
someService.getObjects().then((result) => {
```

What specifically do I need to mock so that the `ObjectList` component can get what it needs to from `SomeService` to set its state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with mocking class instances is that it may be difficult to reach class instance and its methods without having a reference. Since `someService` is local to component module, it can't be accessed directly.

Without specific mock, `jest.mock('./SomeService')` relies on
[class automatic mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) that works in unspecified ways. The question shows that different instances of mocked class have different `getObjects` mocked methods that don't affect each other, despite `getObjects` is prototype method and conforms to `new SomeService().getObjects === new SomeService().getObjects` in unmocked class.

The solution is to not rely on automatic mocking but make it work the way it's expected. A practical way to make mocked method accessible outside class instance is to carry it alongside mocked module. This way `mockGetObjects.mockImplementationOnce` will affect existing `someService`. `mockImplementationOnce` implies that the method can change the implementation later per test:

```
import { mockGetObjects }, SomeService from './SomeService';

jest.mock('./SomeService', () => {
  let mockGetObjects = jest.fn();
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    mockGetObjects,
    default: jest.fn(() => ({ getObjects: mockGetObjects }))
  };
});

...

mockGetObjects.mockImplementationOnce(...);
// instantiate the component
```

If the method should have constant mocked implementation, this simplifies the task because the implementation can be specified in `jest.mock`. It may still be beneficial to expose `mockGetObjects` for assertions.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a benefit to this approach over the one I stumbled upon myself? See my own answer to my question moments ago.

Comment: So, with this approach, would I define `mockGetObjects.mockImplementationOnce` in the test itself to define the behavior of the mock?

Comment: You are free to use `mockGetObjects.mockImplementationOnce`, or `mockGetObjects.mockImplementation` per test, or `mockGetObjects.mockImplementation` in beforeEach, depending on your needs. If you are sure the mock should be the same for all tests, you can do this with `jest.mock` alone like in your answer. Notice that referring to outer mock_data instead of new object on every call may harm tests if the component mutates the object.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with how that would be implemented within the test itself? I've tried a few approaches, most of which give me an error that `Cannot read property 'mockImplementationOnce' of undefined`

Comment: It's supposed to become available as named import from SomeService module.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error playing around with [different approaches suggested in the jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks), the only thing that seemed to work was calling `jest.mock()` with the module factory parameter, like so:

```js
// rename data to start with 'mock' so that the factory can use it
const mock_data = {
  data: require('./test_json/object_list_response.json'),
};

jest.mock('./SomeService', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getObjects: () => {
        return Promise.resolve(mock_data).then(response => response.data)
      }
    };
  });
});

// write tests
```

Using `mockResolvedValue()` didn't work because I couldn't chain `.then()` off of it.

If this leads anyone to a more elegant or idiomatic solution, I'd welcome other answers.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you won't be able to change the implementation of getObjects. Otherwise, yes, that's how it's done. A good use of `jest.mock('./SomeService')` implies the use of manual mock with `__mocks__`, otherwise auto-mock causes more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, another solution is creating a manual mock within a `__mocks__` folder (inspired by Estus Flask's comment and [this documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock)).

`./__mocks__/SomeService.js`

```js
export const mockGetObjects = jest.fn()

const mock = jest.fn(() => {
    return {getObjects: mockGetObjects}
})

export default mock
```

Then the plain `jest.mock('./SomeService')` call works with the implementation later being defined in the test:

```js
mockGetObjects.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  return Promise.resolve(object_data).then(response => response.data)
})
```