# Mock class using JEST in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

So, this is actually something that happened to my several times and I never knew how to solve it.

I have a class like this

```js
//myClass.js
const { get } = require('../models/myModel');

class MyClass {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    async getByID() {
        return get(this.id);
    }
}
```

and a controller that is

```js
//controller.js
module.exports = MyClass;

const MyClass = require('./MyClass.js');

module.exports = {
    getController: (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const MyObject = new MyClass(1);
            const info = await MyObject.getByID();
            res.send(info)
        }
        catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to do an E2E test, i need to mock that `getByID` to see what happen when it resolves and rejects.

So, how do I mock a constructor? I did something like this

```js
// myclass.spec.js


const MyClass = require('./MyClass.js');

jest.mock('./MyClass', () => jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  getByID: Promise.resolve({id: 1, name: 'John'}),
})));


describe('Testing MyClass', () => {
    it('Should return info', () => {
        const res = httpMocks.createResponse();
        const mReq = httpMocks.createRequest();
        const mNext = jest.fn();
        const mRes = mockResponse();
        await pipelineController(mReq, mRes, mNext);
        expect(mRes.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
        done();
    })
})
```

I know this test currently works, but now I cant change that `getByID` mock value to see what happen when it rejects the promise.

If I try to include it inside the test (`it`) .... it won't mock anything...
I want something like

```js
const MyClass = require('./MyClass.js');
const {pipelineController} = require('./controllers.js')

jest.mock('./MyClass', () => jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  getInfo: jest.fn(),
})));


describe('Testing MyClass', () => {
    it('Should return info', () => {
        ProcessService.getInfo.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('the value i want'))
        const res = httpMocks.createResponse();
        const mReq = httpMocks.createRequest();
        const mNext = jest.fn();
        const mRes = mockResponse();
        await pipelineController(mReq, mRes, mNext);
        expect(mRes.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
        done();
    })
    it('Should return info', () => {
        ProcessService.getInfo.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject('the reason i want'))
        const res = httpMocks.createResponse();
        const mReq = httpMocks.createRequest();
        const mNext = jest.fn();
        const mRes = mockResponse();
        await pipelineController(mReq, mRes, mNext);
        expect(mRes.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
        done();
    })

})
```

Comment: That class doesn't make much sense. Why isn't the id an argument to the *method*?

Comment: It's just a brief of the class. The thing I want to learn is how to mock and change the value with jest

Answer (score 0):

Since `getByID` is called right after instantiation, a spy should be available outside mocked class in order to change the implementation.

This can be done with class auto-mock that [works in obscure and unspecified ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63290289/3731501) but may be suitable for this specific case:

```
jest.mock('./MyClass.js')
const MyClass = require('./MyClass.js');
...
MyClass.prototype.getByID.mockResolvedValue({id: 1, name: 'John'});
// instantiate MyClass and call getByID
```

And this can be done by exposing a spy outside the class:

```
const mockGetByID = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../../../services/ProcessService', () => jest.fn(() => (
  { getByID: mockGetByID }
)));
const MyClass = require('./MyClass.js');
...
mockGetByID.mockResolvedValue({id: 1, name: 'John'});
// instantiate MyClass and call getByID
```

Comment: Hi Estus! thank you for your response. This is not currently working. I get a reference error `ReferenceError: const mockGetByID = jest.fn();`

Comment: It's unclear what exactly ReferenceError refers to because it should clearly mention troublesome variable name, did you modify error message when pasting? Updated. mockReturnValue likely should be replaced with a function in order to access mockGetByID lazily.